# Svgs and other mime types in windows azure

Tags: node.js, azure, svg, mime-types

Hi im setting up a website in nodejs on windows azure, and would like to include svg's as background images. how do i allow svgs and mimetypes in general?

Answer (score 7):

Azure uses [IISNode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/)

I added this web.config file to get svgs working. 
It can be modified for other mime types

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
    </staticContent>
    <handlers>
      <add modules="iisnode" name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.js\.logs\/\d+\.txt$"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If Node is serving up the file, just serve it up with the right MIME type (using whatever library you're using). If you're having IIS serve up the file, then you'll need to add the MIME type to your web.config.

Comment: Just to add reference to how to add mime-type to IIS: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/mimeMap

Comment: Node is serving up the files fine when i run it locally (using node-mime via express), but when i push to azure the svgs are not loaded.

Comment: What Content-Type header is it sending out for them?

Comment: I dont really know how to find that, but if the problem only consists on azure, wouldnt the problem have to be when the node server tries to get the files from the underlying system=

Comment: The file system doesn't have anything to do with the HTTP headers your server sends. If you don't know what the Content-Type header (MIME type) is, how do you know that it's the issue? What's the actual symptom you're seeing?

Comment: @smarx im not talking about the file system, i think azure uses iis to serve files to node... ?? 
symptoms :svg's are the only file type (i have found that isn't working), IIS doesnt support svgs out of the box.

Comment: Im pretty sure the solution is to update web.config, but i dont know how to get the one in use, or what a new one should contain

Comment: Okay, there are too many options here... let's try to narrow it down. Of the following, which are you using? 1) Windows Azure Web Sites, 2) a web role in a Windows Azure Cloud Service, 3) a worker role in a Windows Azure Cloud Service. I'm beginning to guess the answer is (1), in which case I think you can just create a file called web.config in the root of your app. In the case of (1), IIS is serving your app, and it's delegating some portion of the requests to your Node.js app. My guess is that the default settings serve static content from IIS, not from your app.

Comment: That sounds likely...
I am  running azure websites