# adding mime type json to azure website with node.js

Tags: azure

I don't have a web.config (that I know of) and I'm using github to deploy my azure website to microsoft windows azure websites.  I went to the azure portal and added a .json mime type with application/json (I tried with .json and json, neither worked).  How can I allow for downloads from standard json files?

Comment: Azure uses iisnode so you can add web.config to your main project directory with mime type specified. Have look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866628/express-nodejs-web-config-in-azure-for-svg-fonts)

Comment: thanks plentysmart.  that worked.  seems odd to add a web.config to a node site and that the azure mime types have no affect from the admin panel.